# What is the meaning of 冲着

Tags: meaning

冲 is a word with many nuances. In my sentence, does this 冲着 have any sense of 'rush'? I take '冲着 ...... 去' to mean 'because' here, although maybe 'intent on', 'aiming at' might be better.

当初，你考美元的时候，是冲着美院油画系，但是您现在画的都是国画。

当初，
Originally,
你考美院的时候，
when you took the Arts College entrance exam,
是冲着美院油画系去的，
a) (that) was because you wanted to study oil painting,
b) you were intent on the Faculty of Oil Painting,
c) you were aiming at the Faculty of Oil Painting,
但是您现在画的都是国画。
but now all you paint is Chinese Painting.

请别冲着我大喊大叫！冲着 = at
海潮冲着峭壁。冲着 = dash against
那幢房子冲着大海。冲着 = faces
其实我就是冲着她来的。冲着 = for
是冲着美院油画系去的，冲着 = because?

Comment: When I looked up "rush" in a dictionary, I also found a lot of meanings. So which sense of "rush" do you mean?

Comment: 他‘迫不及待’地想上那所大学。这样的。

Comment: In that sense, no.

Answer (score 2):

冲 is merged from two different characters, 沖 and 衝, notice that 衝 was merged to 沖 and then simplified to 冲 in simplified Chinese. It is very common that using a simple homophone Chinese character replace another complex one in classic Chinese among ordinary people, this is one of the Chinese simplifying rules. We can see the meanings of the characters 冲 or 沖 is about **water**, yes, it means water (verb), flush, etc. But 衝 is another verb, it means **toward (for somebody or something)** generally. e.g.: 衝向/冲向: run toward, 衝動/冲动: impulse, 衝着/冲着: for (something).

- 请别**冲**着我大喊大叫/請別**衝**著我大喊大叫:
  Please don't shout **at** me.
- 海潮**冲**着峭壁/海潮**沖**著峭壁:
  The tide is **eroding (flushing)** the cliff.
- 那幢房子**冲**着大海/那幢房子**衝**著大海:
  The house **face to** the sea.
- 其实我就是**冲**着她来的/其實我就是**衝**著她來的:
  Actually I'm coming **for** her.
- 是**冲**着美院油画系去的/是**衝**著美院油畫系去的:
  (Someone) is going **for** oil painting department of fine arts academy.

The second 冲 is corresponding to 沖 in traditional Chinese, the others are 衝.

Comment: I searched the sentence 海潮**冲**着峭壁 in Baidu, I got the result **the waves _dashed against_ the cliff**. I think it is also right, if you prefer 冲着 is short for 衝擊著/冲击着, for that the meaning of the combination 冲着 in simplified Chinese is ambiguous.

Comment: 冲着 may be 衝著 (short for 衝擊著 in TC, 冲击着 in SC) or 沖著 (冲着 in SC). So you may consider the sentence as 海潮衝(擊)著峭壁: The tide impacted against the cliff, or 海潮沖著峭壁. The meanings are exact if written in traditional Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

冲 has two pronunciations chōng and chòng.

冲 chōng(verb): rush; charge; pour boiling; flush; etc.

冲 chòng（adj）: Strong(of smell); bluntly, ie 他说话很冲。

冲 chòng（prep）: facing; towards; aim at(metaphorically);

For example:

> 冲南走 // go south
>
> 冲前走 // go straight up

In these example of yours, it means facing or towards(chòng):

> 请别冲着我大喊大叫！冲着 = at
>
> 那幢房子冲着大海。冲着 = towards; facing

In this example:

> 海潮冲着峭壁。冲着 = dash against, 冲 is pronounced as chōng(verb)

In these examples, it means aim at(chòng)(verb):

> 其实我就是冲着她来的。
>
> 是冲着美院油画系去的。

In addition, 冲 has some other meanings too.